# Escalate to glob a directory?

Tags: bash, osx-mavericks

On OS X, I'm writing a bash script to be run as a user, not root. Every so often I need to escalate to root to run certain commands.

In one section I'm trying to iterate over the contents of a directory owned by root with the permissions drwx------, which means I can't glob the contents of the directory as a normal user.

This doesn't work:

```
sudo for files in "/System/Library/User Template"/*
  do
   some command "$files"
  done
```

What I would like to do is this:

```
for files in "/System/Library/User Template"/*
  do
   sudo some command "$files"
  done
```

This is a new system bootstrap script, so I'd like to keep everything in one script and I definitely cannot run the whole thing as root. I'm wondering:

1. If there's a proper way to escalate to glob a directory in a for loop.
2. If I should change the permissions as root, run the code, change the permissions back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can only consider calling another script that's meant to run as root instead and use `sudo` with it.

Although maybe you can run bash reading commands from input:

```
    sudo bash -s <<'EOD'
for files in "/System/Library/User Template"/*; do
    some command "$files"
done
EOD
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Do you think it's better or safer to just place it in another script?

Comment: @WorriedinDenver Depends if the contents are complex. If that's enough for you, perhaps not anymore.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll accept the answer but can't upvote it yet, because I don't have the reputation...

Comment: I see it's ok. Welcome :)